# How to code/run programs in a Docker container using CLion?

Tags: docker, clion

I am a newbie to CLion

I found that CLion has support for Docker.
I want to do the following:

```
(Refer my Linux OS as A.)
(Refer the docker container within A as B.)


The library and environments are set up in B.
The CLion IDE is running in A.
I want to code/debug the program that runs in B using the IDE in A.
```

Is this the functionality that CLion supports?
I read their documents, but I can't find a way to achieve it

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/shuhaoliu/docker-clion-dev

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edit: As of the 2021.3 preview CLion has built in support for docker.
See the [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70284237/9614249) for details.**

---

As of late 2018, [Remote Development](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/09/initial-remote-dev-support-clion/) in CLion is pretty easy to set up. All we have to do is set up a docker container as our "Remote Host".

---

I used the guide at https://github.com/shuhaoliu/docker-clion-dev as a reference and made a few changes. Here is what worked for me:

(Optional) If you do not have the Docker plugin for CLion installed, get it by following [these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/docker.html).

## Step 1 - Dockerfile

Modify the [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/shuhaoliu/docker-clion-dev/blob/441e6dd1dbda2e35f50c1af35077d363010febad/Dockerfile) to install any dependencies your project needs. Add the Dockerfile to your project.

```
FROM ubuntu:cosmic

########################################################
# Essential packages for remote debugging and login in
########################################################

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils gcc g++ openssh-server cmake build-essential gdb gdbserver rsync vim 

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

# 22 for ssh server. 7777 for gdb server.
EXPOSE 22 7777

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash debugger
RUN echo 'debugger:pwd' | chpasswd

########################################################
# Add custom packages and development environment here
########################################################

########################################################

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

## Step 2 - Docker Compose

In the same directory as the previous docker file, create a docker-compose.yaml file.

```
# From: https://github.com/shuhaoliu/docker-clion-dev/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  gdbserver:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: clion_dev
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    container_name: debug
    ports:
      - "7776:22"
      - "7777:7777"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/debugger/code
    working_dir: /home/debugger/code
    hostname: debug
```

## Step 3

Ensure that the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files are in the same directory.

### Option 3A (With CLion Docker Plugin)

Right-click the `docker-compose.yml` file and select `Run`.

[image]

After a minute or two the container should be created and be viewable from Clion's Docker tab.

[image]

### Option 3B (Without CLion Docker Plugin)

From the directory containing the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files, run:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

## Step 4 - Configure Toolchain

Open ***Settings->Build, Execution, Deplyment -> Toolchains*** and create a new **Remote Host** Toolchain.

In the **Credentials** field click the small folder on the right side and enter the credentials for the debugger user created in the Dockerfile.

In the example above the username is "debugger" and the password is "pwd".

[image: Remote toolchain]

## Step 5 - CMake Profile

Now we must set up a CMake profile to make use of our new Remote Host toolchain.

Navigate to ***Settings->Build, Execution, Deplyment -> Cmake*** and create a new profile. The only necessary change is selecting the toolchain created in the previous step.

[image: Cmake Profile]

## Step 6 - Running/Debugging the Program

From the CMake tab, make sure that you have the newly created CMake profile selected.

[image]

After the CMake project loads into the container, you should be able to select the CMakeProfile you would like to use in the run configuration switcher in the top right corner of CLion.

[image]

Hopefully if everything went well you should now be able to run and ebug code in a docker container!

---

If things didn't quite go according to plan, here are some references that helped me get things working:

- [docker-clion-dev Guide](https://github.com/shuhaoliu/docker-clion-dev)
- [CLion Remote Project Guide](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/09/initial-remote-dev-support-clion/)
- [Clion CMake Profiles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profile.html)
- [CLion CMake Toolchains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/how-to-create-toolchain-in-clion.html)

Comment: Ive had issues using this technique. Mostly that environment variables passed to the docker launch or set during the docker build are not available to the ssh session. Any thought on how to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

As of CLion 2021.3 EAP there is a [built in Docker Toolchain](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2021/10/clion-2021-3-eap-new-docker-toolchain/#new_docker_toolchain).

Taken directly from the [CLion blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2021/10/clion-2021-3-eap-new-docker-toolchain/#new_docker_toolchain):

> 1. Go to Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains.
> 2. Add a new toolchain, select Docker type.
> 3. Create a docker server and select it in the toolchain settings.
> 4. Select one of the available Docker images.

[image: img]

> Now you can create CMake profiles using this Docker toolchain:

[image: img]

Check the [full blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2021/10/clion-2021-3-eap-new-docker-toolchain/#new_docker_toolchain) for more details and tips on how to set up and optimize the docker toolchain on different platforms!

Answer (score 2):

It may be not very regular way to do it, but you can actually run a CLion itself inside a docker container. This may be useful if parsing your codebase requires some libraries which you have only in docker but not on your system (I did it to work with ROS). Also you don't need to mess with "remote developement" long loading and syncing time, also debugger works "out of the box".

Example of such setup may be found [here](https://github.com/kurron/docker-clion).